# create nix store path with .cargo/registry by running 'cargo' using nix (mkDerivation or similar)

Tags: rust, nix

## hacky way

i have this code in nix to generate a `.cargo` cache:

```
myVendoredSrc = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "myVendoredSrc";
    # i renamed .cargo into cargo to make this work
    src = /home/joachim/cargo;
    phases = [ "unpackPhase" "installPhase" ];
    installPhase = ''
      mkdir -p $out/.cargo
      cp -R registry $out/.cargo
    '';
  };
```

i use this cargo-cache in a `nix-build` project like this:

```
  buildenv = import ./artiq-dev.nix {
    extraProfile = ''
      export HOME=${myVendoredSrc}
    '';
    # --no-compile-gateware to disable vivado build
    runScript = "python -m artiq.gateware.targets.kasli -V satellite --no-compile-gateware";
  };
```

this later calls `cargo build` and uses the cache without the reqirement to connect to the internet.

in nixpkgs there is fetchcargo, see https://github.com/alexcrichton/cargo-vendor

## question

idea: figure out how to use `<nixpkgs>/pkgs/build-support/rust/fetchcargo.nix` in my own nix files...

## what i tried before

please don't hint me to use `carnix` (i tried it build it didn't work every well and i also found out that i can't use it for this project) or `buildRustPackage` or `buildRustCrate` (same reason, this can't be used for the project i'm working on since it is a cross compiler setup which is setup form a python script creating serveral environment variables)

Answer (score 1):

this is the code i came up with finally:

```
let 
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  fetchcargo = import <nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/rust/fetchcargo.nix> {
    inherit (pkgs) stdenv cacert git rust cargo-vendor;
  };
  myVendoredSrcFetchCargo = fetchcargo rec {
    name = "myVendoredSrcFetchCargo";
    sourceRoot = null;
    srcs = null;
    src = ../artiq/firmware;
    cargoUpdateHook = "";
    patches = [];
    sha256 = "1xzjn9i4rkd9124v2gbdplsgsvp1hlx7czdgc58n316vsnrkbr86";
  };

  myVendoredSrc = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "myVendoredSrc";
    src = myVendoredSrcFetchCargo;
    phases = [ "unpackPhase" "installPhase" ];
    installPhase = ''
      mkdir -p $out/.cargo/registry
      cat > $out/.cargo/config << EOF
        [source.crates-io]
        registry = "https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
        replace-with = "vendored-sources"
        [source."https://github.com/m-labs/libfringe"]
        git = "https://github.com/m-labs/libfringe"
        rev = "b8a6d8f"
        replace-with = "vendored-sources"
        [source.vendored-sources]
        directory = "$out/.cargo/registry"
      EOF
      cp -R * $out/.cargo/registry
    '';
  };

  buildenv = import ./artiq-dev.nix { inherit pkgs; };

in pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "artiq-board";
  src = null;
  phases = [ "buildPhase" "installPhase" ];
  buildPhase = 
    ''
    ${buildenv}/bin/artiq-dev -c "HOME=${myVendoredSrc} python -m artiq.gateware.targets.kasli -V satellite --no-compile-gateware"
    '';
  installPhase =
    ''
    mkdir $out
    #cp artiq_kasli/satellite/gateware/top.bit $out
    cp artiq_kasli/satellite/software/bootloader/bootloader.bin $out
    cp artiq_kasli/satellite/software/satman/satman.{elf,fbi} $out
    '';
}
```